# Redirect Specific Pages Then Redirect All Others

Tags: .htaccess

Where to start.

I need to move a website to a new subdomain with around 20 specific pages, and then just blank redirect everything else.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect specific pages
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)$ http://newdomain.com/path/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(index2\.html)$ http://newdomain.com/path/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(index3\.html)$ http://newdomain.com/path/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

# Redirect all others to the new domain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Customize and test for your situation using: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/